# I get 302 redirect several times until I reach the maximum redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

In my web page I have different URL for each language. The main language is spanish so for example if in spanish I have the following: www.mywebpage.com/coche, in english I have this: www.mywebpage.com/en/car

The problem is that I am getting 302 status code until I reach the maximum number of redirects when I am using the english links and in spanish it works well (status code 200). I don´t see the difference of what I am doing in spanish or in english to get the proper url so I don´t understand why is this happening.

Since this is happening in all the pages of the webpage I really don´t know what peace of code to put here. I really don´t know where is it failing. I put some break points and try to debug but I didn´t see a place where is passing over and over wicth is apparently what is going on.

Here I put the details of what is happening when I use the english url:

```
1. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=f0dr1jnqq2qa4lm1jftn5o40;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:31 GMT
    Content-Length: 149

Redirecting to http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona ...

2. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=slqb1bj3frbj4qaxlds3lt0r;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:32 GMT
    Content-Length: 149

Redirecting to http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona ...

3. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=kgl4jgtiykww0jzc0eto4q0x;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:32 GMT
    Content-Length: 149

Redirecting to http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona ...

4. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=evphastef4ccmydel4zxfdvp;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:32 GMT
    Content-Length: 149

Redirecting to http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona ...

5. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=2a5oz1cxf1ajcpzig3k4mpjv;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:32 GMT
    Content-Length: 149

Redirecting to http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona ...

6. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    GET /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Location: /en/rental/camper-vans/barcelona
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=lnmxt4jabm2pjztzvr5quajv;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:48:33 GMT
    Content-Length: 149
```

And here what happens when I use the spanish one:

```
1. REQUESTING: http://www.mywebpage.com/alquilar/furgonetas-camper/barcelona
    GET /alquilar/furgonetas-camper/barcelona HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Host: www.mywebpage.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

SERVER RESPONSE: 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=2yjzrmhrbzynnegjn3ch5tqf;
    path=/; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: cookiePolicy=1;
    expires="Tue, 03-Jun-2025 10:50:09 GMT"; path=/
    Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=; expires="Mon, 11-Oct-1999 22:00:00 GMT";
    path=/; HttpOnly
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 10:50:10 GMT
    Content-Length: 107767
```

**EDIT:**

I go on trying to see what is going on and I discovered more things that I put in this thread to make the question more accurate of what is happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638289/how-to-avoid-double-redirect-in-asp-net-iis

Comment: Is there any code in global.asax.cs to check for culture to load the correct resource strings?

Comment: I use the following for each language `oUrlResolver = new UrlResolver(pLanguage, new local.ServiceClient().GetPageURL(pLanguage));` and then with what we get from there (basically a list of urls per language) you create the diferent urls.

Comment: Can you put a break point in the ServiceClient/GetPageUrl method and see if there is some difference in Request. Alternatively just pass in a hard coded pLanguage value and see if it makes any change.

Comment: No this cannot be the problem because it reach the correct page and actually after the get the maximum redirect number the page loads correctly. So the url itself works fine. We checked the global.asax url creation before.